# Is clock_getres the proper function for obtaining the resolution for Ubuntu 16.04 clock_gettime()?

Tags: ubuntu, clock, floating-point

Is clock_getres the proper function for obtaining the resolution for Ubuntu 16.04 clock_gettime()?

If it is , how do I use the result to do this calculation?

64 bit integer has 15 base 10 digits of precision. For IEEE 754-2008 Standard decimal64, the 52 bit double precision significand provides 53 bits of resolution. I was hoping for a formula.

@Julie Pelletier told me her stellar test results a day ago which
are that the best possible time granularity for Linux clock_gettime is 5 millisecond

Comment: For example, if  the number of nanoseconds between two distinct points in time is 13109440541795 ns. If I only need 12 base 10 digits of precision because of my realtime clock's resolution limit, I would expect to see 13109440541000 nsec. Does this sound logical? My feelings will not be hust by criticism. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made one measurement of clock_gettime resolution with :

```
    struct timespec now;
    struct timespec resolution;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &resolution);
    printf("secs %d  nanoseconds %d\n",resolution.tv_sec, resolution.tv_nsec);
```

The result is:

lacrosse@lacrosse-ThinkStation-S10:~/Debug$ ./a.out
secs 0  nanoseconds 1

This result was different than what I expected after reading the on-line documents from Rutgers University Computer Science department which stated 
that it would be much higher(i.e 1 second).